# How to set domain to Many2One fields in odoo?

Tags: odoo

I have an entity teacher with a Many2One field "substitute_teacher_id". The idea is that a teacher can replace other teacher, but a teacher should not be able to replace himself. How can I set that restriction in the teacher's model and/or view to ensure that a teacher cannot select a teacher with the same id as a substitute? This is my code

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    _name = 'school.teacher'
    _description = 'School Teacher'

    name = fields.Char(string="Name")
    substitute_teacher_id = fields.Many2one('school.teacher', string="Sustitute")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expose `id` field before `substitute_teacher_id` field in from view.

Now add following domain in it:

```
<field name="substitute_teacher_id" domain="[('id', '!=', id)]"/>
```

**EDIT:**

```
<field name="id" invisible="1"/>
<field name="substitute_teacher_id" domain="[('id', '!=', id)]"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by  " expose id ", i am sorry but I am new with odoo, could you be a little more specific?

Comment: @tico1993 I have edited my answer. Expose means add `id` field on form view side.

Comment: Thank you so much, 
I just found out that you can aply the domain to the model as well
`substitute_teacher_id = fields.Many2one('school.teacher', string="Sustitute",domain="[('id', '!=', id)]")`